# xsl:strip-space combined with xsl:text messes up automatic indentation

Tags: xslt

Using XSLT 1.0 I would like to comment out certain XML elements and replace other XML elements, while keeping the XML nicely formatted.

For example, the following XML document

```
<doc>
  <e1>foo</e1>
  <e2>bar</e2>
</doc>
```

should be converted to

```
<doc>
  <!--<e1>foo</e1>-->
  <e3>foobar</e3>
  <e4>foobar</e4>
</doc>
```

I am using the following XSL transformation and `xsltproc` for testing it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e1">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text> <!--*-->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text> <!--*-->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e2">
    <e3>foobar</e3><e4>foobar</e4>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But what I get is this:

```
<doc><!--<e1>foo</e1>--><e3>foobar</e3><e4>foobar</e4></doc>
```

The problem seems to be caused by the lines marked with '*' in my transformation; more specifically from inserting `<!--` and `-->`. When I remove these two elements, the result is indented as expected.

Is there a way to wrap elements in comments while still keeping the output document nicely formatted?

Comment: What happens if you put a real comment in there with e.g. `<xsl:template match="e1"><xsl:comment>...</xsl:comment></xsl:template>`, does xsltproc then indent the contents of the `doc` element?

Comment: The indentation works correctly when using `xsl:comment` but as you probably know only text nodes are allowed inside `xsl:comment`. `xsltproc` doesn't complain but the output then is `<!--foo-->` instead of `<!--<e1>foo</e1>-->`.

Comment: Well, you can compute the serialization using XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try whether outputting a comment with the serialization of the element, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e1">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:call-template name="xml-to-string"></xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="e2">
        <e3>foobar</e3><e4>foobar</e4>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you a better result.

Comment: `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` is missing, but otherwise this seems to work. I guess the external dependency on `xml-to-string` isn't easy to avoid?

Comment: Well, in a daily application I wouldn't recommend pulling it from the web for every use but instead install a local copy in the file system. As for the approach, I don't know whether xsltproc allows you to do serialization with an extension function so you could avoid doing the serialization in XSLT. Of course with the simple contents you have (e.g. `<e1>foo</e1>`) it might be tempting to do the serialization with a few templates on your own but such attempts then produce some not well-formed serialization sooner or later and whoever needs to parse the comment's content runs into problems.

Comment: I'd rather avoid using any extension function, so I'll either use a local copy of `xml-to-string` or reconsider doing the indentation in a second pass. Thank you very much for your help!